# android listview is iterating through the footer menus too

Tags: java, android, menu, android-listview

This is my activity code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] names = new String[] { "Investor Relations", "Social Sharing", "Rate this app", "About Rathbones",
            "Disclaimer", "Security", "Credits"};
    // Create an ArrayAdapter, that will actually make the Strings above
    // appear in the ListView
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.moremenulist,
            R.id.label, names));
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Get the item that was clicked
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String keyword = o.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And here is the xml file for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label"></TextView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    
          <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imgbtn1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgbtn3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/topnews" android:visibility="visible"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:id="@+id/imgbtn5" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgbtn4" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/more"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/contact_us" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgbtn1"></ImageButton>
    
</RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
        
        
 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, when the activity is loading it is appending the menu with each item in the list. I just want it to appear only in bottom not with each and every list item.
any suggestions?

## Edit-1 :

I tried this but getting an error of nullpointer exception

```
View footerView = 
        

    ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
        ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        lv.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by menu? Do you mean your ImageButtons?

If that's the case then remove those create another layout for those ImageButtons and add them using [ListView.addFooterView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) instead.

You could create e.g. `list_footer_layout.xml`, which contains your ImageButtons. Then:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ...
    ListView lv = getListView(); // If your activity is ListActivity
    View foot = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_footer_layout, null);
    lv.addFooterView(foot);
}
```

Comment: Yes, i mean that imagebutton only. How can I use that addfooterview method?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot and your current layout files? Are you using ListActivity?